# How to build recommendation model for calling prospects

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

My goal is to better target prospects at a higher call success rate, based on time of day and prior history.

I have created a "Prodprobability" column showing the probability of a PropertyID answering the phone at that hour for the history of calls. Instead of merely omitting Property ID 233303.13 from any calls, I want to retarget them into hour 13 or hour 16 (the sample data doesn't show but the probability of pickup at those hours are 100% and 25% respectively).

So, moving forward, based on hour of day, and history of that prospect picking up the phone or not during that hour, I'd like to re-target every prospect during the hours they're most likely to pick up.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeNpA.jpg)

EDIT: I guess I need a formula to do this: If "S425=0", I want to search for where "A425" has the highest probability in the S column, and return the hour and probability for that "PropertyID". Hopefully that makes sense.

EDIT: :[sample date returns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x41pL.jpg)

Comment: So whats your expected output suppose to be? Can you provide sample code/data  in R language?

Comment: I have coded as much to be able to get the order of most-least probable calls, but I am looking to retarget the 0 probability ones at the end of the list into hours where they are more likely to be picked up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question here would be are you dead set on creating a 'model' or an automation works for you?

I would suggest ordering the dataframe by probability of picking the call every hour (so you can give the more probable leads first) and then further sorting them by number of calls on that day.

Something along the lines of:

```
require(dplyr)

todaysCall = df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(propertyID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(noOfCalls = n())

hourlyCalls = df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(hour == format(Sys.time(),"%H")) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(todaysCall) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(Prodprobability),noOfCalls)
```

Essentially, getting the probability of pickups are what models are all about and you already seem to have that information.

**Alternate solution**

Get top 5 calling times for each propertyID

```
top5Times = df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Prodprobability != 0) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(propertyID) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(Prodprobability)) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1:5L) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Get alternate calling time for cases with zero Prodprobability:

```
zeroProb = df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Prodprobability == 0)

alternateTimes = df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(propertyID %in% zeroProb$propertyID) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Prodprobability != 0) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(propertyID,desc(Prodprobability))
```

Best calling hour for cases with zero probability at given time:

```
#Identifies the zero prob cases; can be by hour or at a particular instant
zeroProb = df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Prodprobability == 0)

#Gets the highest calling probability and corresponding closest hour if probability is same for more than one timeslot

bestTimeForZero = df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(propertyID %in% zeroProb$propertyID) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Prodprobability != 0) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(propertyID) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(Prodprobability),hour) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1L) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Returning number of records as per original df:

```
zeroProb = df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Prodprobability == 0) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(propertyID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(total = n())

bestTimesList = lapply(1:nrow(zeroProb),function(i){
  limit = zeroProb$total[i]

  bestTime = df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(propertyID == zeroProb$propertyID[i]) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(desc(Prodprobability)) %>% 
    dplyr::slice(1:limit)

  return(bestTime)
})

bestTimeDf = bind_rows(bestTimesList)
```

Note: You can combine the filter statements; I have written them separate to highlight what each step does.

Comment: Yes, I have been able to do that. I'd just like to also take the 0 probability records and give them a new "hour" value for where I should be targeting them. Basically, half of my records are 0 probability ones and if I can re-target them into hours with better probabilities, my average goes way up.

Comment: So the expected output is all possible times a particular ```propertyID``` can be called?

Comment: that would work, but I was thinking an output (for 0 probability records only) that is the max value of probability elsewhere in the sheet, along with the corresponding hour for that max probability

Comment: @KellyJackson, check the updated code. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Interesting, yes this is looking good. Is there a way to replace each propertyID with 0 probability with its highest probability and the corresponding hour? So my end df is the same number of records?

Comment: Almost there, thanks so much for your help. So, I'd like to end up with the same number of records at the end, including duplicates so I make the same number of calls in the next campaign (if one propertyID has two 0 probabilities, I'd like to replace them with two of the max probability records). Can this be done too?

Comment: @KellyJackson, yes, give me some time.

Comment: @KellyJackson, please check the updated code at the end. This should dynamically give the best 'n' records. This can give 0 probability cases which I have kept in case the number of non-zero records is lesser than the number of 0 records. If you don't want these records, a simple filter at the end should help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting an end result bestTimeDf that is much smaller than the original df

Comment: @KellyJackson, can you share a sample of the data such that it can be reproduced? Are there any specific areas where you are observing lesser records?

Comment: I added the sample data from the original df. It will be everything including many columns I'm not interested in. Is this how you'd like me to send the sample data?

Comment: After running the bottom chunk of code you have posted, I end up with approximately 68,000 rows.

Comment: @KellyJackson, no. Something like ```df = data.frame('propertyId'=c(1,2,3),'Prodprobability' = c(0,0.2,1.0),hour=c(4,6,7))```. Only send the rows where results are not as expected and send only the columns required.

Comment: @KellyJackson, can you tell me what is the output of ```table(df$Prodprobability)```?

Comment: oh sorry. Yes, the output shows ~68000 "0" probabilities, with the remaining ranging up to 1. When I run the last chunk above, I am left with ~68000 rows from the 0 probabilities I guess?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So you have a replacement row for each of the 0 probability cases as you wanted.

Comment: ok got it, my fault. So I just need to remove the 0 probabilities in the original, then add this df correct?

Comment: Yep, that should give you all non-zero probabilities.

Comment: @KellyJackson, please do mark my answer as correct if it solves your problem.